# Make an API call after onDestroy is called for an Activity

Tags: android, ondestroy

On Android, after an activity's onDestroy is called, I need to make an API call. What is the best way to do it ?

I have tried calling an intent Service but its not running after the app is closed.

Comment: What do you mean with API call? What do you want to do? What you have tried...please enlighten us....

Comment: yes you can do with service

Comment: edited the equestion

Comment: You can do pretty much whatever you want in onDestroy.  But what do you mean by "API Call" ?

Comment: I need to send an analytics report that the app has been closed.

Comment: Can you try by invoking a BroadcastReceiver in your onDestroy method and do the API call statements there.

Comment: @FebiMathew. How to do that ?

Comment: How important is this API call?  Because there's no guarantee that `onDestroy()` will be called at all.

Comment: Either you can go for Intent Service(in case of one small work) or STICKY service (in case of long time and repetitive work)

Answer (score 2):

if app is force closed `onStop`  and `ondestroy`  won't be called ,according to documentation `onPause` method is the last method which will be surely called
so better make your api call in `onPause` method

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) is what you are looking for. It can be applied via the registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks method of [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class.

Comment: Better to give a link without urls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Intent Service for achieving your Goal, use that service in onDestroy()

you can have a look at following example.

http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android

Answer (score 0):

It's better start service in onStop instead of onDestroy, in my case work like a charm, hopefully may work for

```
  @Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    startService(new Intent(this, ServerCall.class));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

public class ServerCall extends Service {

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    Log.d("MyApp","Service started");
    goActive("0");
}



public void goActive(final String status) {

    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            GO_ACTIVE,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    //    Log.d("MyApp",response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("MyApp", error.toString());

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            Log.d("MyApp", SharedpreferenceUtility.getInstance().getString(Constants.KEY_EMAIL));
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", SharedpreferenceUtility.getInstance().getString(Constants.KEY_EMAIL));
            params.put("status", status);
            return params;
        }

    };
    EarningChamp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(sr);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}